# Timer stopping too early

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I am trying to get the countdown timer to stop and show the game over view controller when the timer hits 0. It counts down by .1. The problem is that when the timer is at 2.0 it stops and shows the game over screen. I don't know why this happening because the 'if' statement the code says `if seconds & milliseconds == 0` should work and show the game over screen when the countdown hits 0.

```
var timer = Timer()
var seconds = 2
var milliseconds = 0

timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(SecondViewController.countDownfunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func countDownfunction() {

    time.text = "Time: " + "\(seconds).\(milliseconds)"

    if milliseconds == 0 {

        seconds -= 1
        milliseconds = 10
    } else {
        milliseconds -= 1
  }
    if seconds & milliseconds == 0 {

        timer.invalidate()

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showGameOver", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 second is 1000 milliseconds. 0.1 seconds is 100 milliseconds. And you must not use a counter to track time. Use `Date`.

Comment: When I do 100 milliseconds it takes 10 seconds for it to count down 1 second

Comment: It needs to be `if milliseconds == 0 { seconds -= 1 milliseconds = 900 } else { milliseconds -= 100 }`. But again, get rid of both `seconds` and `milliseconds`. Use `Date` to track the total elapsed time.

Comment: @rmaddy is actually right, you are waiting 100 ms too long, by initializing miliseconds with 10, you should initialize it with 9 or 900, like rmaddy suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `if seconds & milliseconds == 0 {` to:

```
if seconds == 0 && milliseconds == 0 {
```

single `&` is a bitwise AND operator: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html)

you perform bitwise AND calculation on 1 and 10: 0001 & 1010 = 0 and compare the result with 0, so in this case your if-clause is being called.

EDIT: changed condition to fit && operator...

Comment: what do you mean by 10: 0001 & 1010 = 0 ?

Comment: 1 & 10 = 0001 & 1010 = 0000 = 0. check the link I provided for further explanation. Look for `Bitwise AND Operator`, they have an example, of how it will be calculated

Answer (score 1):

This is because the code is evaluating seconds & milliseconds first, getting an answer of false, which is equal to 0, so it returns true and shows game over. 
Instead,

```
if(seconds == 0 && milliseconds == 0)
{

}
```

Comment: `getting an answer of false`. `seconds & milliseconds` doesn't return `false`. Its bitwise calculation, that returns `0`. Btw. `false` is not equal to `0`, at least not in swift.